# Testing that 404 page has been rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I currently have tests that ensure that certain actions are `not_routable` with Rspec:

```
it 'does not route to #create' do
  expect(post: '/sectors').to_not be_routable
end

it 'does not route to #show' do
  expect(get: '/sectors/1').to_not be_routable
end
```

But I have changed the way my exceptions are handled by using `rescue_from` in my `ApplicationController`.

Routes:

```
get '*unmatched_route', to: 'application#raise_not_found'
```

Application Controller:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :not_found

def not_found
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404", :layout => false, :status => :not_found }
    format.xml { head :not_found }
    format.any { head :not_found }
  end
end

def raise_not_found
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new("No route matches #{params[:unmatched_route]}")
end
```

I can't quite work out though how to construct a test that checks the 404 page and its contents get rendered:

```
it 'does not route to #create' do
    post: '/sectors'
    expect(response.status).to eq(404)
    expect(response).to render_template(:file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html")
  end
```

I get an error on `post: '/sectors'`, how do I simulate the post request in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Request Specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) for this.

Your test should look like:

```
  it 'does not route to #create' do
    post '/sectors'
    expect(response.status).to eq(404)
    expect(response).to render_template(:file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html")
  end
```

Notice that post here is not a symbol, it is a method call.

Comment: ah thanks very much, weirdly though i now get `ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] "/sectors"`, guess i just need to add `post '*unmatched_route', to: 'application#raise_not_found'` to my routes?